# Reading last line from Std input when last line does not contain a new line character

Tags: java

Well I know this is a pretty basic question but somehow I am not able to figure it out.

I have an input similar to say:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

All the lines have a new line character at the end except line4 i.e. I have pressed ENTER after each line except line4. Now if I provide this as an input to the BufferedReader, it reads out only the first 3 lines and skips the last line.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){  
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This is the code I am trying to use. I dont think there is any problem with the code and no new line at the last line is causing the problem.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: `readLine()` as the name implies, reads a line. There is no line until you press enter (how would the program know that you wont press more keys?)

Comment: Yes correct ... So how to go with such a situation... In no way can we read the last line then .. I am copying this entire thing to the input of the program and it starts running without allowing me to press an enter

Comment: In your example, after entering "line4", how do you indicate to the program that you're finished typing?

Answer (score 0):

From [BufferedReader's readLine() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Meaning, if you want to "read" a line, it has to have one of those characters mentioned above.